# Help identifying 4 weird Duplo pieces

Tags: part-identification, duplo

I don't collect Duplo so I'm not familiar with a lot of the pieces they have. Here are the four that stump me:
[image: duplo bricks]
[image: duplo brick]

- 4x10x3-ish freight hopper: I searched "duplo hopper" in BrickLink but only got [this](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=31303&name=Duplo,%20Train%20Freight%20Hopper%20Compartment&category=%5BDUPLO,%20Train%5D)
- 2x2 brick with axle(?). The axles are hollow up to the edge of the brick
- 2x2 blue dome brick with eyes and a clip. The studs are hollow
- 5x5-ish dome bricks with a 2x2 centre. They have two tiny holes in the bottom, and a groove at the top. Initially I thought they belonged with the [tube](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=31195&name=Duplo%20Ball%20Tube%2045%20degrees&category=%5BDUPLO%5D) system pieces because I have several of those, but the circle size is too big for that.

None have dates on them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The yellow piece looks like 40637 [Duplo, Brick 2 x 2 with Digger Bucket Arm Holder](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=40637&idColor=3#T=C&C=3).

[image: 40637 Duplo, Brick 2 x 2 with Digger Bucket Arm Holder]

Answer (score 6):

I just found the answers to 75% of my question! I was scrolling BrickLink for "duplo tube" since I have several of those pieces, then found the blue dome with eyes: it's "[Duplo Ball Tube Cover Ring Hinged Top with Eyes](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=40711pb01&idColor=7)". It only appears in [one set](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=3266-1), and attaches to [another piece](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=40710&idColor=3) which I don't have, which then connects to the tubes, so that's why I didn't know it related to the tube pieces.

In this set's inventory, I then found two more of my pieces: the green hopper, which is "[Duplo Loading Chute with 2 x 4 Base Bricks](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=31025&idColor=6)", and the red/blue inverted domes, which are "[Duplo Egg Base](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=31367&idColor=7)". So I was right about the bases relating to the tubes, but they don't actually connect to them, they just sit there.

I haven't identified the yellow axle brick though!